# Create a dynamic picture in JSX using Struct parameters?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a cryptoKitties Dapp and want to create a dynamic picture based on my Struct parameters. When a kitty is breeded or minted I create a Struct with random features of the kitty, like hair color, eye color, gender etc. In my table I want to add a dynamic picture of each kitty based on these parameters.

I mostly write in solidity, do truffle tests and write some frontend, so Im not really savvy in this area or JSX, so any example based on my code would be great :) I was trying something with canvas but got only errors.

[image]

Comment: please add sample code in codesandbox for debugging is great

Comment: Hmm codesandbox ? , never used it before... Does the code I provided in the pic not help you ? thx